# OnMessageReceived not called when app in off for a long time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to receive data on my application even if it's kill or in background using data message from FireBase.
It works well if the app has been used in the last 2 days (approximately) but after, onMessageReceived() is never call anymore.

Any idea of why this happens?

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> response = remoteMessage.getData();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("tokens", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!response.get("sender").equals(sharedPref.getString("FMC_token", "Error2"))) {
        StorageService.getInstance().downloadFile(response.get("image_path"), "crt", getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: If user doesn't interact with your app it's subject to being put in a lower priority [standby bucket](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby) which might limit how oftem it can receive FCM messages. You can see if whitelisting your app in battery optimization helps, if it doesn't then there's no other way to fix it than restructuring your app so it requires more user interaction to keep itself in higher priority bucket.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work :/